# programmatically clean solution using devenv

Tags: c#, devenv

I am trying to clean all the projects in solution from code behind using C#. I have use devenv clean commnad, my method is executed properly without any exception but no action is performed on the solution. All project's bin and obj folder in my solution still contains the compiler generated files. Please let me know where is the problem.

C# code

```
 public string CleanSolution(BO.Project project)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(project.SolutionFilePath)) return "Solution file not found";
            var cleanCommand = "Devenv  " + project.SolutionFilePath + " /Clean";

            //var cleanProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe", cleanCommand);
            //if (cleanProcess != null) cleanProcess.WaitForExit();

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%comspec%");
            startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@"/c ""c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" && devenv.com ""{0}"" /Clean",project.SolutionFilePath);
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.Start();
            // Read the error stream first and then wait.
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
            while (!process.HasExited)
            {
                q.Append(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
            string r = q.ToString();
            var message = "Clean Succeeded";
            IsClean = true;
            return message;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return string.Format("Message: {0}", e.Message) + Environment.NewLine +
                   string.Format("Stack Tracke: {0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, e.StackTrace) + Environment.NewLine +
                   (e.InnerException != null
                        ? string.Format("Inner Exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message) + Environment.NewLine
                        : string.Empty) + Environment.NewLine +
                   (e.InnerException != null
                        ? string.Format("Inner Exception Stack Tracke: {0}", e.InnerException.StackTrace) +
                          Environment.NewLine
                        : string.Empty) + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
```

I tried to redirect the output of process so as to see what happens but I am getting empty string as its final output in variable **processOutput**

Comment: You may need to look at "StandardError" instead.

Comment: What is _commnad_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how it works, you cannot use `vcvarsall` as command and `devenv ...` as arguments.

As `ProcessStartInfo.FileName` use "cmd.exe", or better:

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%comspec%")
```

As `ProcessStartInfo.Arguments` use:

```
@"/c <...>\vcvarsall.bat && devenv.com <...>"
```

Where `<...>` are the fragments (directory, arguments, etc.) you already have in your code.

Note that you should use explicitly use `devenv.com` (windowless command line version), to make sure that not `devenv.exe` (normal application) is used.

To make things more robust, you should make sure that your paths are properly quoted.

Here is the full example:

```
startInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%comspec%")
startInfo.Arguments = string.Format(
   @"/c """"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" && devenv.com ""{0}"" /Clean""",
   project.SolutionFilePath);
```

Comment: I tried the changes suggested by you but still clean is not performed my bin & obj still contains compiler generated files

Comment: What happens when you run the command (as build by `FileName` and `Arguments`) in a command prompt window?

Comment: actually I am calling the CleanSolution() from my web application inside the controller I just get my success message-"Clean Succeeded". My CleanSolution() is defined in my service.

Comment: Further troubleshooting requires that you see the output of the actual command being executed. So either run it manually, as I suggested in the previous comment, or redirect the `Process` output and write it somewhere (log, etc.) - for the later there are plenty examples on SO.

Comment: I have redirected the process output but getting empty string, please see the code above

Comment: See my comment on your question (you might also need to look at `StandardError`).

Comment: getting the error-"'c:\\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n", I think its not reading the entire path provided

Comment: Yes, please review that you have correctly quoted your paths (as shown in my example). In case of doubt, please update your question with your _latest actual_ code.

Comment: please see the code I have updated it to the latest one which I am using

Comment: See my updated answer. You need an extra pair of quotes.

Comment: just wanted to ask is there a way to get the log of the clean operation.Basically I want the log similar to the visual studio log when we manually clean the solution

Comment: The respective messages should go to standard output or standard error, just grab them. In any case, you should ask a new question about this issue.

Comment: suddenly again clean operation stopped working,not getting any standard error but clean is not performed